# Not finding libgdx projects to import them

Tags: eclipse, libgdx, eclipse-adt

I bought a new computer and installed Eclipse on it. After the ADT plugin finished downloading I tried to import my projects (composed of 4 sub-projects), but Eclipse doesn't see them!

I just click `"import/general/import existing projects into workspace"`, select the folder containing the sub projects, hit the open button but Eclipse says `"No projects found to import"`.

I'm using Eclipse Kepler and the projects files are directly taken from Eclipse Juno.

Comment: Your other android projects are working on new eclipse?

Comment: does your project folder contain .project file. may be absence of this file may be causing the problem

Comment: yup, there is no .project file

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse need .project file to import the projects into workspace. what you can do is create a new project and copy the source and libraries into that project

Alternative method can be that create a new project and copy the .project file from that project to your project but make sure you edit the .project file and change the name of that project according to your project. read this for more information on .project file

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fproject_description_file.html

I will suggest you to use the First method .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've tried to:

- Refresh everything
- Searched for Nested Items
- Go to (In the libg-gdx setup) Advanced >> Check Eclipse
- And if that doesn't work, add a .project file into the folder manually